# How to edit cue texts of .vtt tracks in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, html5-video, subtitle

I'm trying to edit cue texts of .vtt tracks in a Rails Application. My Application should get the current cue and make possible to the user to change the text of that cue, changing the track. I'm getting the new text through a form, and it's ok. 
I've searched on the web some solution and tried a lot of them, but I have no success. I've got to change the text of the track, but if I reload the page it get back to the same old track, in other words, it's changing the text, but doesn't modifying the track file.

```
var videoTime = videoElement.currentTime;
var cues = textTrack.activeCues;
//track.activeCues(Retorna as cues ativas)
var cue;
var startTime;
var endTime;

        if(cues.length > 0){
            cue = cues[0];
            console.log("Cue capturada");
            startTime = cue.startTime;
            endTime = cue.endTime;
        }

        if(videoTime >= startTime && videoTime <= endTime){
            cue.text = novaLegenda.value; //novaLegenda is the form field
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not changing the file, you are just modifying the data in memory.

You must sync that information to the server so you can reload it with changes.

After every change, send that change to the server, via AJAX, and let the server process another version of the file.

It is better if you have a Modeled version of the subtitles, that way it will be much easier to make the changes.